# Vue-resource respone parsed to JSON has attributes with 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I am using vue-resource to make HTTP requests to my back end.

```
getVehicle() {
    this.$http.get(`website/vehicle/${this.$route.params.id}/`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.vehicle = data;
        });
}
```

I am expecting an objects with a lot of attributes.
When I console log the response itself - everything looks OK:

```
(...)"clc\":false,\"ltr\":false,\"sud\":false,\"rsw\":false,\"tdo\":false,\"fdo\":false,(...)
```

However, when I console log the data, there are items that have "undefined"
values.
​

```
afl: undefined
aib: undefined
```

I expect this has to do something with the promises but I do not know what the issue is.

Any help will me much appreciated.

Regards,
Teodor

Comment: Maybe the response is formatted incorrectly/in a way that json() misinterprets the data?

Comment: I verify this at several places so it should not be the reason. I really think it is something caused by the asynchronicity (I don't know why it is called asynchronous when it is actually synchronous) but I cannot figure out how to handle this.